# preg_replace small big character

Tags: preg-replace, character

i have a database within Peter, Franz ... (some names)

and this is my code:

```
preg_replace("/".$query."/i","<b>".$query."</b>",$row->nick,-1);
```

wenn i type in a search query "pet(...)" he replace the original (big cap) "P et(...)"

But i want this: **Pet**er

give me a hint ;)

```
$abfrage = mysql_query("SELECT id, nick FROM user WHERE nick LIKE '%".$query."%' LIMIT 5");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($abfrage)) {
   $higlignick=preg_replace("/".$query."/i","<b>".$query."</b>",$row->nick,-1);
   echo '<a style="color:black;" href="users.php?u='.$row->id.'">'.$higlignick.'</a><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
$highlightnick = preg_replace("/$query/i", "<b>$0</b>", $row->nick);
```